# libboost version when installing GNURadio in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnuradio

I am trying to make and install GNU Radio in ubuntu 13.04. I know that I should have libboost1.53-all-dev because the 1.49 version is not compatible. However, when I tried to install uhd, it requires libboost-all-dev, which is of version 1.49. Moreover, the 1.49 version and 1.53 version cannot exist on the same machine. I wonder how you guys solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. In 13.04, the only way to install both UHD and GNURadio is to compile UHD manually. I have removed all the boost packages of version 1.49 and installed all the packages of version 1.53. After that, compile UHD according to the build guide on the UHD website. Then, compile GNURadio.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this page](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/UbuntuInstall#Raring-Ringtail-1304) you can paste the apt-get command to install all necessary packages for building the gnuradio package. You can also use apt-get build-dep as long as your source code repositories are enabled.

Comment: Thanks, but this do not solve my problem. The command on that page ask me to install libboost1.53 and will remove libboost-all-dev automatically. Then I cannot have UHD installed.